# custom image in section - problems with transparency?

Tags: ios, uitableview, transparency

i am confused with custom background image in section.

i have set an custom image and on the top of the table the transparency of the image is not showing correctly.

[image]

The place where it should be transparent is black, see the border.

When i am starting to scroll the table, the black block is gone.

[image]

Whats the problem here? I dont understand it.

TableView Infos:
Width of tableView:
**728px**

width of backgroundimage in section header:
**728px(708px + 10px left transparency and shadow+ 10px right transparency and shadow).**

width of backgroundimage in cell:
**728px(708px + 10px left transparency and shadow+ 10px right transparency and shadow).**

Thanks for help,
brush51

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be solved with this:

Set the opaque to NO AND the **layer opaque**, too!

```
[view.layer setOpaque:NO];
view.opaque = NO;
```